Does inputrc syntax permit nested conditional blocks?
As inputrc only has "if", "else" and "endif" and does not have an "else if" conditional statment, are nested conditionals permitted, viz a second "if" within an "else" block?
For example
$if term=lxterm
 ...
$else
$if term=rxvt
...
$else
$if term=xterm
...
$endif
$endif
$endif


Yes. I don't know if this is documented, but it would be really weird if it didn't work since this is such a basic feature. In any case, I tested with the following in my ~/.inputrc and can confirm it does work:
$if term=xterm-256color
# Quote the current or previous word
"\C-xq": "\eb\"\ef\""
$else
 $if term=bob
   "\C-xq": "\eb\'\ef\'"
 $else
   "\C-xq": "\eb-\ef-"
 $endif
$endif

My default terminal, terminator uses TERM=xterm-256color, there, Ctrl+xq placed double quotes around the last word. I then ran export TERM=bob and then xterm, and in the xterm window that opened (where TERM as set to bob), the same keyboard shortcut single quoted the word, so we entered the first nested $if. Finally, in a pure xterm where  TERM=xterm which matches the $else of the nested $if, as expected, the shortcut placed - around the word.
So yes, empirically, inputrc allows for nested $if statements.

Thank you for the confirmation that it does work as my web searches drew a blank on this and all the inputrc files I have seen supplied by distributions eg Debian and openSuse never do this but just have  linear  $if term=a ... endif $if term = b ... endif which is surely less efficient than the nested case.
